# Finding a Basis for a Vector Space V Spanned by $S = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ spanned by $S =\{ v_1 = \sin^2x,\ v_2 = \cos^2x,\  v_3 = \cos2x\}$.

For the first part of the problem, I'm required to show that $S$ is not a basis for $V$ and in the second part, I need to find a basis for $V$.

I know that $S$ is not a basis for $V$ because the Wronskian of the three functions is equal to $0$, meaning the vectors are linearly dependent; however, I can't seem to figure out how to go about finding a basis for $V$.

I understand a basis to be a set of linearly independent vectors spanning $V$, but how would I find that set?

Comment: $v_1$ and $v_2$ forms a basis for $V$. Note: $cos(2x)= cos^2(x)-sin^2(x)$.

Comment: $\dots =2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
v_3=\cos 2x= \cos^2 x- \sin^2 x= v_2-v_1
$$
so it is a linear combination of $v_1,v_2$, 
but
$
a \sin^2x +b \cos^2 x=0 \quad \forall x
$
only if $a=b=0$